# Google Script to hide rows by 2 conditions, One word and one date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the first question I have posted on Stack Overflow so I apologize if I am doing this wrong. I have a tracker for work where I am trying to hide rows with a script that meets 2 conditions. 1. If a row contains "rejected" or "withdrew" 2. Date older than the previous quarter (in this case 1/1/2022). I can get the script to hide rows with just the words no problem but I have no clue how to do the date because I think it is a different syntax.

The dates are in column K, M, O, Q, S, U, W.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    function Hide() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var sheetI = 1; sheetI <= 3; sheetI++) {
    var sheet = sheets[sheetI];
    sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var s = ss.getSheetByName("Data Validation");
    var v = s.getRange("A2").getValues(); 
    
    
    var kk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var k = kk.getSheetByName("SM");

    var a = k.getRange("K:K").getValue();
    var b = k.getRange("M:M").getValue();
    var c = k.getRange("O:O").getValue();
    var d = k.getRange("Q:Q").getValue();
    var e = k.getRange("S:S").getValue();
    var f = k.getRange("U:U").getValue();
    var g = k.getRange("W:W").getValue(); 

    var colJ = sheet.getRange("J:J").getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});
    var colL = sheet.getRange("L:L").getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});
    var colN = sheet.getRange("N:N").getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});
    var colP = sheet.getRange("P:P").getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});
    var colR = sheet.getRange("R:R").getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});
    var colT = sheet.getRange("T:T").getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});
    var colV = sheet.getRange("V:V").getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});

    colJ.forEach(function(value, rowI) {
      if (value === "rejected" && a < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
      }    
    else if (value === "withdrew" && a < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
    }   
    });     

    colL.forEach(function(value, rowI) {
      if (value === "rejected" && b < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
      }
    
    else if (value === "withdrew" && b < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
    }   
    });     

    colN.forEach(function(value, rowI) 
    {
      if (value === "rejected" && c < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
      }    
    else if (value === "withdrew" && c < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
    }   
    });
     

    colP.forEach(function(value, rowI) {
      if (value === "rejected" && d < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
      }    
    else if (value === "withdrew" && d < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
    }   
    });
     

    colR.forEach(function(value, rowI) {
      if (value === "rejected" && e < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
      }    
    else if (value === "withdrew" && e < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
    }   
    });
     

    colT.forEach(function(value, rowI) {
      if (value === "rejected" && f < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
      }    
    else if (value === "withdrew" && f < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
    }   
    });
     

    colV.forEach(function(value, rowI) {
      if (value === "accepted" && g < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
      }    
    else if (value === "declined" && g < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
    }   
   else if (value === "didn't extend" && g < v) {
        sheet.hideRows(rowI + 1, 1);
    }
    });
    
  }
  
}
```

[Original look of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z41RY.png)

[Intended Look of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJcB0.png)

Comment: you are correct! I edited it to show the right images now

Comment: There are a lot of getRange and getValue calls. I suggest you assign them on variables to reduce the calls.

Comment: Would you be able to share a demo sheet with the dummy values? Also, if you would want to test it out, you could utilize the `new Date()` js method for this condition.

Comment: If you wish to compare dates numerically then you should use the methods getTime() or valueOf().  You should consider getting all of each sheets data at one time and analyze it all at one time.  The code will run much faster.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10_pX4OaHiJcesYDGWAlys42l-0BEMlGeui9YAYZZK20/edit?usp=sharing) here is a demo sheet with dummy values!

Comment: @Cooper the dates are in column K, M, O, Q, S, U, W. I also shared a dummy sheet with the same information!

Comment: Which columns contain the strings you are looking for.

Comment: @Cooper The text strings of "rejected" and "withdrew: are in Columns J, L, N, P, R, T, V

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody dares to dive deep into this problem (me included) for now, here is the partial solution.

This function returns `true` if a given date doesn't belong to current quarter:

```js
function is_the_date_old_enough(checked_date) {

  // which quarter the date belongs
  const get_quarter_of = date => Math.ceil((date.getMonth()+1)/3); 

  // number of quarters in current date
  var cur_date = new Date();
  var cur_date_years = cur_date.getFullYear();
  var cur_date_quarts = cur_date_years * 4 + get_quarter_of(cur_date);

  // number of quarters in checked date
  var checked_date_years = checked_date.getFullYear();
  var checked_date_quarts = checked_date_years * 4 + get_quarter_of(checked_date);

  // if the difference bigger than zero
  return (cur_date_quarts - checked_date_quarts) > 0;
}

// tests  (current date: 2022-01-14)
console.log(is_the_date_old_enough(new Date()));             // false always
console.log(is_the_date_old_enough(new Date('2021-12-20'))); // true
console.log(is_the_date_old_enough(new Date('2021-09-05'))); // true
console.log(is_the_date_old_enough(new Date('2022-01-05'))); // false
console.log(is_the_date_old_enough(new Date('2000-01-05'))); // true
console.log(is_the_date_old_enough(new Date('2030-01-05'))); // false
```

Beware, the timezones can get you a headache for dates around first and last days of month. If you need to handle timezones it may require a more complicated solution. I suspect the variable `cur_date` should be defined with '00:00:00.00' time or something like that.